# GET call to REST API returns null

Tags: angularjs, api, rest

I am trying to make a GET call to test a REST API but it keeps returning null, is there anything I am doing wrong:

**Making the call in controller.js**

```
function ConsumerSearchCtrl($scope, BusinessCategoryService) {

    console.log(BusinessCategoryService);

}
```

[image]

**127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/ works perfectly fine**

[image]

**Code in services.js for API**

```
/**
 *
 */
function BusinessCategoryService(WenzeyAPI, $q) {

    var scope = this;

    scope.categories = categories;

    function categories() {
        var q = $q.defer();
        WenzeyAPI.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/').then(function success (res) {
            q.resolve(res.data);
        }, function failure (err) {
            q.reject(err);
        })
        return q.promise;

    }

}



/**
 *
 */
function WenzeyAPI() {

    var scope = this,
        ip = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

    scope.get = get;
    scope.post = post;

    function get(url, data) {

        data = data || {};

        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: data
        }

        var q = $q.defer();
        $http(req).then(function success(response) {
            q.resolve(response);
        }, function failure(err) {
            q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    function post(url, data) {

        data = data || {};

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data
        }

        var q = $q.defer();
        $http(req).then(function success(response) {
            q.resolve(response);
        }, function failure(err) {
            q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

}
```

Comment: with the browser dev tools, is there any error message in the console tab?  anything interesting in the network tab (corresponding to the GET request)?  you mentioned that it worked against localhost.  what's the URL that's failing?

Comment: It works when I access it in localhost, but it doesn't work from the Javascript application

Comment: There are no error message in browser dev tools

Comment: What does `doesn't work from the Javascript application` mean? What exactly is returning `null`

Comment: Whenever I make the call in controller.js

Comment: Note that using `$q.promise` is anti-pattern when `$http` already returns  promise https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: That's not very defintitive. Is `BusinessCategoryService` an angular  factory or service

Comment: @charlietfl `BusinessCategoryService` is a service

Comment: Check the network tab to see if the request is dispatched from the browser. Also check the console for any errors.

Comment: @SaneeshB just checked, seems the request isn't dispatched from the browser. No errors as well

Comment: Add a breakpoint in WenzeyAPI.get . does it reach at that point ?

Comment: You not calling `BusinessCategoryService.categories` in your example code which is the bit that actually returns the promise for your network access. You really should just return the promise from `$http` instead of making your own, finally you really should refrain from using the variable `scope` to describe your context, services/factories cannot inject `$scope` it could confuse future developers.

Comment: Is the JavaScript running from the same host and port?

Comment: @ste2425 how should the code look like

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde for Javascript, http://localhost:8100/... for API http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: @methuselah yup, your problem is known as "same-origin policy". Your browser will not let your JS do XmlHttpRequest to another origin (domain + port) because of security implications.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde tested it with this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en, still no error message

Comment: @methuselah yeah, still, I'm convinced that this is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `WenzeyAPI` and using `$http` resolved it.

```
function BusinessCategoryService($http) {

    this.getAllData = function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/',
        });

    }

}
```